# Runtime error running coverage with sonarq and jdk11

Tags: java, maven, java-11, sonar-maven-plugin

I have an error running the coverage with sonarq.
i'm using jdk11, jacoco 0.8.6

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and i'm running sonarq with this command

```
mvn verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -Psonar
```

this is error stack

```
java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing 
C:\_Git\cl\repo\proyecto\src\connector\DataSourceConnectorImpl.class
at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:157)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:129)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:152)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeClassFile(JacocoReportReader.java:139)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeFiles(JacocoReportReader.java:114)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.readExecutionData(UnitTestAnalyzer.java:126)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.analyse(UnitTestAnalyzer.java:95)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.execute(JaCoCoSensor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:160)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:143)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:127)
        ... 61 common frames omitted
```

what could be the problem? i already updated the jacoco version and the sonarq runtime command to last one (3.9.0.2155) without get any improve

edit: i added the completely stack error

Comment: `.class` in `src` folder is somewhat smelly! ;)

Comment: try using the updated version for Java-11 class file compatibility `mvn verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.0.2155:sonar -Psonar`

Comment: i already use that version tu run the sonarq command

Comment: the stack trace hints `org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass`, so you could execute jacoco report goal individually to narrow down the cause. not straightforward to reproduce this without exact setup details.. or you could figure out `mvn dependency:tree` ends up with asm version which is not compatible.

Comment: i added the completely stack error

Comment: **.class files should be** (for a normal maven plugin usage) **in `target/classes`!!!** (I understand, when jacoco plugin and anything else is confused otherwise.)

Comment: Please upgrade the used version: `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar` this version is from 2017... simply to old... use the most recent version... https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin

Comment: Also check the structure of your project because `proyecto\src\connector\DataS..` this looks wrong...